# jQuery cache refreshing checkbox radio button state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, state, browser-cache

I've just found out that my checkbox/radio buttons keep their previous state in ie/ff when doing a normal refresh, F5. Is there something i can put in the javascript/jQuery to make their state reset? Do I have to go through each one manually and go `$(selector).prop("checked",false)` or is there an easier way?

 I know about ctrl+F5, but I want the state to reset on just F5.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably leave that browser behaviour *as is*. It is what the end user will expect.

However, *if* you wanted to do this, you could probably do `$('#your-form')[0].reset()`.